# insert_many with upsert - PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have some data like this:

```
data = [{'_id': 1, 'val': 5},
        {'_id': 2, 'val': 1}}]
```

current data in db:

```
>>> db.collection.find_one()
    {'_id': 1, 'val': 3}
```

I ***always*** receive unique rows but am not sure if any of them already exists in DB (such as the case above). And I want to update them based on two types of requirements.

**Requirement 1**:

*Do **NOT** update the rows if `_id` already exists.* This is kinda easy in a way:

```
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
try:
  db.collection.insert_many(data, unordered=False)
except BulkWriteError:
  pass
```

executing the above would insert `2nd` row but won't update the first; but it also raises the exception.

***1.*** Is there any better way of doing the above operation (for bulk inserts) ?

***Requirement 2***

This is similar to `update_if_exists` & `insert if not exists` combined. So the following data:

```
data2 = [{'_id': 1, 'val': 9},
         {'_id': 3, 'val': 4}}]
```

should update the row with `_id=1` and insert the `2nd` row in DB.

The problem is I get thousands of rows at one time and am not sure if checking and updating one-by-one is efficient.

***2.*** Is this requirement possible in MongoDB without iterating over each row and with as few operations as possible ?

Answer (score 12):

You can generate a list of updates to pass to [bulk write API](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) that will send all the operations together but they will still be executed one by one on the server, but without causing an error.

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne
data2 = [{'_id': 1, 'val': 9}, {'_id': 3, 'val': 4}]
upserts=[ UpdateOne({'_id':x['_id']}, {'$setOnInsert':x}, upsert=True) for x in data2]
result = db.test.bulk_write(upserts)
```

You can see in the result that when _id is found the operation is a no-op, but when it's not found, it's an insert.

Comment: Shouldnt this be [unordered](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations) ?

Comment: no, that wouldn't achieve what the OP described.